# It it possible to use existing SQLite database in windows phone?

Tags: database, sqlite, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am newbie to windows phone development.  I have a requirement to develop a app which was developed in Android and iOS. I need to use the same SQLite database which was used in Android and iOS. Is it possible to use existing  SQLite database in windows phone? If it is yes how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

[for basic setup of sqlite use this link](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/working-with-sqlite-in-windows-phone-8-a-sqlite-net-version-for-mobile/)

first add the database file to project and change its properties to COPYALWAYS and "CONTENT" and now copy it to you local folder and make connection to the database using sqlite like this.

```
 public static SQLiteAsyncConnection connection;
    public static bool isDatabaseExisting;
    public static async void ConnectToDB()
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFile storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("DatabaseFinal.db");
            isDatabaseExisting = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            isDatabaseExisting = false;
        }
 if (!isDatabaseExisting)
        {
            try
            {
                StorageFile databaseFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("DatabaseFinal.db");
                await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
                isDatabaseExisting = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                isDatabaseExisting = false;
            }
        }

        if(isDatabaseExisting)
        connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "DelhiMetroDatabaseFinal.db"), true);
    }
}
```

}

this will create your connection too and for using databse for getting data from your db file use can use query like this

```
  public List<dataclass> getdata(string line_id, ref Boolean isdata)
    {
        List<datadataclass> query = new List<datadataclass>();

        try
        {
            query = dal.connection.Table<dataclass>().Where(i => i._id == line_id).ToListAsync().Result;
            isdataclass = true;
            return query;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException e)
        {
            isdataclass = false;
        }

        return query;
    }
```

data class will have properties as your column defined in you database.

```
class dataclass
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int location { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I wanted to know if I want to access the existing Sqlite Database from location other than my project path, how can I achieve the same? the reason I am asking because when I try to assign the db_path and execute app it throws exception that database could not be found.

Comment: why do you want to do that it is good to have all your resources in your project local folder.

Comment: The reason I was asking because, I was looking for the flexibility to keep the db at one path, and use single instance for all the versions of app i.e. android, iphone.

Comment: if your app on ios and android is already developed and released on store then i think the problem you facing not a problem at all.And if your app on ios and android is not released and you want make a common data base then you have to store your data on some server(windows azure)so that your app on all platform would be synchronized.